# how to add constraints driver without driver modifier via python

Tags: python

If i add a driver to constraints (head_tail) via python it generates automatically a driver modifier(generator) instead of keyframes.

```
import bpy

rig = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
dr = rig.driver_add('pose.bones["drb"].constraints["Copy Transforms"].head_tail').driver
dr.type = 'SCRIPTED'
dr.expression = 'x' 


var = dr.variables.new()
var.name = 'x'
var.type = 'SINGLE_PROP'


tar = var.targets[0]
tar.id = rig
tar.data_path = 'pose.bones["ctrl"].location[1]'
```

It seems to be the default behaviour.
I tried also to find the driver modifier to remove it but where is this modifier located?

Comment: You can have either keyframes or a driver "driving" a property. How do you envision having both?

Comment: sorry to be so unprecise. I was talking about the interpolation curve in the driver editor (graph editor).If i would add a driver manuelly a interpolation curve (Fcurve) with two keyframes appears but if i add a driver via python a Fcurve modifier (generator) appears instead of keyframes.